# Putting html within a php array

Tags: php

I'm having problems with the syntax for a php array.

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
$data = array();
foreach($pages as $post){
  setup_postdata($post);
  $fields = get_fields(); 
  $data[] = '<p>'.$fields->company_name.'</p><img src="'.$fields->company_logo."' />';
}
wp_reset_query();

// the js array
echo 'var marker_data = ' . json_encode($data) . ';'; // Instead of implode
?>
```

Specifically this line:

```
$data[] = '<p>'.$fields->company_name.'</p><img src="'.$fields->company_logo."' />';
```

I'm getting all kinds of errors with adding the img tag, how would I format it correctly?

Comment: Voting to close as not constructive. It's not the first question of yours which should never have been posted because if you'd use the proper tools you would have been told by your tool that your quotes are wrong.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: And another "let me teach him nothing by simply down-voting his question" response?

Comment: @Alexander You're right but this question should never have been asked in the first place, because Rob doesn't take his lessons it seems.

Comment: The funny thing about it is: even the SO syntax coloring shows the problem clearly!

Comment: @Alexander unfortunately, this is Q&A site, not online tutorial.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel fortunately I never said otherwise, and him asking a Question and people giving him Answers is precisely what just happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data[] = '<p>' . $fields->company_name . '</p><img src="' . $fields->company_logo. '" />';
```

You just changed the `'"` to `"'` which was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Change that line

```
$data[] = '<p>'.$fields->company_name.'</p><img src="'.$fields->company_logo."' />';
```

to

```
$data[] = '<p>'.$fields->company_name.'</p><img src="'.$fields->company_logo.'" />';
```

The problem is after the `$fields->company_logo`.

You have enter `"'` instead of `'"`